ListAction - Integration Procedure
Please, I'm new to Integration Procedures.
I'm trying to implement the solution described below:
Group By a field with a DataRaptor Transform
I don't get it for the 3.2 Step on the answer. How can I use a List Action to extract all Quote Lines for the given ProductSiteName, How to configure that.
Thanks.

I had a look at the linked answer, and Step 3.2 is incorrect. You should use the formula FILTER to extract all the QuoteLines for a given ProductSiteName. Thanks for highlighting it.
Let's say you have a list of QuoteLineItems:
"QuoteLine": [
    {
      "ProductSiteName": "BO1",
      "ProductId": "Prod1",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Number": 1,
      "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
    },
    {
      "ProductSiteName": "S0-1",
      "ProductId": "Prod2",
      "Quantity": 15,
      "Number": 2,
      "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
    },
    {
      "ProductSiteName: "S0-1",
      "ProductId": "Prod3",
      "Quantity": 7,
      "Number": 3,
      "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
    }
]

You can then use the FILTER formula to extract all the list items where the ProductSiteName is a certain value:
FILTER(LIST(%QuoteLine%),'ProductSiteName=="S0-1"')

This will then give you an answer of
[
  {
    "ProductSiteName": "S0-1",
    "ProductId": "Prod2",
    "Quantity": 15,
    "Number": 2,
    "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
  },
  {
    "ProductSiteName": "S0-1",
    "ProductId": "Prod3",
    "Quantity": 7,
    "Number": 3,
    "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
  }
]

Which can then be returned and used to build up the required JSON output. If you want to use a variable to search for a given ProductSiteName then have a look at the documentation on how to do it.
Good luck!

Thank You @Adriaan

@user149765 glad it was useful! Good luck with Integration Procedures!
